# How to add dynamic content inside the iframe..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am creating an iframe element using javascript having src="", because i dont want to load the html from a url. I want to change the html of the iframe using the javascript. My iframe element is

```
window.onload = function () {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div id="myModal" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">';
    html += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Preview</h4></div>';
    html += '<div class="modal-body" style="height:450px; width:100%; margin-top: -17px; margin-left: -17px;">';
    html += '<iframe id="myiframe" src="" onload="editContent();" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:fixed;border-width: 0;" allowtransparency="true">';
    html += '</iframe></div></div></div></div>';
    document.body.innerHTML += html;

    var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe'),
        iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframedoc.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Test h1</h1><h2>Test h2</h2><h3>Test h3</h3><h4>Test h4</h4><h5>Test h5</h5><h6>Test h6</h6>';
}
```

But it will not added the content inside the iframe and still the iframe is empty if i am looking in the console. What is the error there..?

Comment: Your code should, and does, work absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/oam44y0e/. Please check the console for errors, and update your answer to include a working example of the issue

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan when i am looking in the console, there is nothing inside the body element of iframe. Also browser not rendering anything

Comment: I am writhing my js code inside window.load event

Comment: As you can see from the fiddle, it works absolutely fine. We need to see your code that doesn't work in order to help you. There's not enough information here.

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan i edited my question, now you can see what i am doing, i am creating the html inside window load and inside that only i am trying to change the html of iframe. I noticed that first its adding the inner html and after that it removed. Any reason..?

Comment: That still works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/oam44y0e/1/

Comment: But for my side its not working, because i am making an embed script to display my data using that embed script like  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost.abc.com/7jaGJFo/embed.js"></script>

Comment: So long as the script loads properly the source of it has no effect. You need to diagnose the source of the problem yourself if you cannot produce an example - remove the code line by line until it works for you

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan the problem is my script is not getting properly loaded before am using my code, i used settimeout() and now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem, i am trying to add the html data inside the iframe before it is properly created. So i used the settimeout() and write my js code to add the inner html inside that. So its working fine now.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe'),
        iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframedoc.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Test h1</h1><h2>Test h2</h2><h3>Test h3</h3><h4>Test h4</h4><h5>Test h5</h5><h6>Test h6</h6>';
},500);
```